# Ansible roles and tags

Tags: ansible, tags, roles

I have some issues tagging tasks in roles.

I need to put some sql in sync mode, update some for patching with other hosts, and after etc

When i run my playbook i pass the tags different ways. I tried all sort of ways

Ans in the roles tasks i tag the tasks in the files with the tags i want to associate

When i use a main.yml, it tried to run all the tasks in the main regardless of the tagging, for the first host on the first line

When i dont use a main.yml or its empty the hosts tagging works but it does not run the playbook, only gather facts

here is my playbook:

```
---
- name: put sql in sync mode
  hosts: v1sql02d
  roles:
    - role: winupdates
      tags: [ sync ]

- name: update sql not on primary
  hosts: v3sqlax01d, v3sql01d, v1sql03d
  roles:
    - role: winupdates
      tags: [ updates ]
```

here is my main.yml

```
- name: run sql ag sync tasks
  include: winagsync.yml tags=sync

- name: update sql on secondary
  include: winupdates.yml tags=updates
```

here is my first task in tasks

```
  win_shell: |
    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

    Powershell lines
  tags:
  - sync
```

and my winupdate one

```
  win_updates:
    state: searched
    server_selection: default
    register: update_count
    debug: var=update_count
    log_path: c:\ansible_win_updates.log
  tags:
    - updates

- name: Install Updates, Security and Critical
  win_updates:
    state: installed
    server_selection: default
    register: update_count
    debug: var=update_count
    log_path: c:\ansible_win_updates.log
    reboot: yes
  tags:
    - updates
```

Please enlight me or help me

Thanks

Theoneakta

Comment: Tags on a role call are not filtering tasks inside your role. Adding tag(s) to your role stanza is exactly the same thing as if you would add the same tag(s) to all tasks in your role. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles.

Comment: can you add your `ansible-playbook` command to your question. I feel this is related to `apply` option. Do take a look at last example here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html.